# change the default android keyboard using ADB or java code

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am building a custom application that uses specific keyboard so when the user run the application, the default keyboard should be changed to my specific keyboard which name is hackers keyboard , How can I do that using java code or by calling adb command from java code , my device is rooted , again this is specific app and the company that I developing for require that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the `ime` command to set `input method`.

```
$ adb shell ime
usage: ime list [-a] [-s]
       ime enable ID
       ime disable ID
       ime set ID
```

Comment: I used this command ime set org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard/.LatinIME to solve my problem

Comment: `ime enable ID` and then `ime set ID`

Comment: ex. `adb shell ime list -a` gives you `mId=kl.ime.oh/.I mSettingsActivityName=kl.ime.oh.Settings`. Anything to the right of `mId=` is your ID.  Then `adb shell ime enable ID` and `adb shell ime set ID`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`KeyboardView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html) in your application to open your own Keyboard. Therefore you should overwrite `OnTouchListener` of for example the edit textbox.

There is no need to have a rooted device nor to use adb.
There is also an example in the Android SDK. It is called "SoftKeyboard".

Or you could have a look for an example on this [blog post](http://www.infiniterecursion.us/2011/02/android-activity-custom-keyboard.html).

Comment: I am using http://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/ keyboard , can I do what I want with your method and how?

Comment: I don't want to put the source code of my keyboard in my project,I want to keep it in separate project ,how can I do that ?