# Preferring a custom keyboard if available

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I have made a [custom system keyboard](https://github.com/xaviershay/RubixKeyboard). In [another application](https://github.com/aricneto/TwistyTimer/) that I'm also the author of, I would like to set this as the "default" method for various input fields if available. The user should still be able to switch back to their standard keyboard, and it should also present a standard keyboard if the custom one is not installed.

I'm not really sure how this all fits in with [InputMethodManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) or [IMEs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) so am not sure which APIs to be looking at. I'm also open to the idea of packaging my custom keyboard in directly with the application if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to set this as the "default" method for various input field in another application if available

That is not possible, for privacy and security reasons. The *user* needs to activate your IME and the *user* needs to choose what IME to use by default. Otherwise, malware authors would be competing with each other to see whose IME can get control to sniff on user input.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm asking. I'm the author of an application that knows about a separate IME that should be used if available/activated. I will edit my question to make this clearer.

Comment: @XavierShay: That doesn't really change the crux of my answer. An app cannot set the IME to be used for any scope (individual widget, individual app, entire device). That is purely under user control.

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47948/how-to-change-input-method-with-ime-command) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253983/change-the-default-android-keyboard-using-adb-or-java-code), it is possible to set `input method` using `IME` command (or via `ADB`).

Regards

Comment: not sure how this helps me ... and end user is going to be installing from the play store and won't have command line access.

Answer (score 0):

you can open your own keyboard programatically with [KeyboardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html)

so when the user decides to use the default keyboard jet show a dialog and use this according to the answer